# Как получить массив из строки, чтобы там не было ключей?

Tags: php

PHP 8.
У меня есть строка '1,2'.
Мне нужно получить массив с цифрами из строки [1,2].
Я делаю

```
explode(',', $string);
```

Но получаю

```
['0'=>1,'1'=>2]
```

Мне нужно использовать в Ларавел в методе sync как показано в документации https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations
Если я просто вставляю [1,2] то все работает. Если [0=>1,1=>2] то ругается на ключ 0
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Comment: Это какой-то нонсенс. Всё равно что яблоко со вкусом апельсина, а скорее, яблоко с семечками, но  без яблока

Comment: Массивов без ключей не бывает в принципе, вопрос лишь в том, как мы этот массив потом выводите куда либо, он может быть отображен на экране как с ключами, так и без

Comment: Мне нужно использовать в Ларавел в методе sync как показано в документации https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Comment: Если я просто вставляю [1,2] то все работает. Если [0=>1,1=>2] то ругается на ключ 0

Comment: значит нужны ключи числовые а не строковые

Comment: а ещё более вероятно что ты не так вставляешь и пишешь код в целом

Comment: Мне по ключам массива вообще не надо делать sync. Только по значениям. 0 - это не верное значение

Comment: Ты бы основы языка для начала выучил и внимательно потом доки ларавел.  А то сейчас "мне не надо по ключам" - выглядит очень ...не очень

Comment: Вы запутались сами @Alex, и поэтому не получаете нужным вам результат. При использовании explode ЗНАЧЕНИЕ = строка, ключ - ЧИСЛО, и у вас массив не тот что вы привели, а [0 => '1', 1 => '2'];

Answer (score -2):

В PHP8 значения действительно нужно менять:

```
array_map('intval', explode(',', $string))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]